# Clearing an Item from Prefetch Cache in 9.2

Tags: caching

We have based our implementation on
[Clear Sitecore cache for an item from cache programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220196/clear-sitecore-cache-for-an-item-from-cache-programmatically) to clear an item from prefetch cache as below

```
Cache prefetchCache = GetPrefetchCache(Database database);
prefetchCache.RemoveKeysContaining(itemID.ToString());

private Cache GetPrefetchCache(Database database)
    {
        foreach (var cache in global::Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.GetAllCaches())
        {
            if (cache.Name.Contains(string.Format("Prefetch data({0})", database.Name)))
            {
                return cache;
            }
        }
    }
```

But the Cache class of 8.2 is modified to `ICacheInfo` in 9.2 and `RemoveKeysContaining` is not available. Is there any way to remove a particular item from `prefetchCache` in 9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore has changed the implementation to `ICacheInfo`. However, you can still use the method `RemoveKeysContaining` on the cache once you have applied the Sitecore.Caching.Cache casting.

The `ICacheInfo` has multiple implementations and the class `Cache` is one of the implementation.

Please see below code snippet:

```
Cache prefetchCache = GetPrefetchCache(database);

//Check for null before applying method
if (prefetchCache != null)
{
    prefetchCache.RemoveKeysContaining(itemID.ToString());
}

private Cache GetPrefetchCache(Database database)
{
    foreach (var cache in global::Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.GetAllCaches())
    {
        if (cache.Name.Contains(string.Format("Prefetch data({0})", database.Name)))
        {
            return cache as Cache;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the Cache is from the namespace `Sitecore.Caching.Cache` from assembly `Sitecore.Kernel.dll`

Comment: thanks Hishaam. will do the change and test.

Comment: this worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Just an update for Sitecore 9.3 and higher:*

In Sitecore 9.3 almost all of caches are generic and have types like **Cache<T**>. And **Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.GetAllCaches()** contains a list these caches that have different class types. Almost all of them are not castable to **Cache** and return *null* on casting "*cache as Cache*".

So only one working that I found is:

```
var prefetchCache = CacheManager.FindCacheByName<ID>("SqlDataProvider - Prefetch data(" + database + ")");
if (prefetchCache != null)
{
     prefetchCache.Remove(itemId);
}
```

And one helpful picture "just to know" how item caching works before hitting  database:
[image]